# How to get the address that the client type on the Address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to identify the client typed the page address in the Address bar.
I need this information before the request is sent.
Probably in the event `onbeforeunload`

Comment: Your development should not rely too much on the browser. Some browsers don't even have support many features.

Comment: Do you need the full URL? Or do you want to detect when the user types in something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except when the navigation is caused by something in page (e.g. clicking a link) there is no way for the previous page to find out where a user has navigated to.

It would allow for some serious privacy violations if it was possible.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. There is a way to get the browser indication whether he stays or goes through my site to another site?

Comment: You can capture click events on links, submit events on forms, and any location assignments you put in your JavaScript, but you can't detect navigation destination directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you should be able to get the full URL from `document.location`, (so `var URLstring = document.location;` for example).

Comment: It's `window.location` (source w3c)

Comment: There is a `document.location` (although I believe it is deprecated) too, but either of them will give you the URL of the current page, not what the user has just typed into the address bar in order to leave your page and go to a different one.